# How to change sql to mongodb query language?

Tags: sql, mongodb

How to change sql to mongodb query language like this

```sql
 select count(case when isA=1 then 1 else 0 end ) as Acount,count(case when isB=1 then 1 else 0 end ) as Bcount from Table1
```

I want to  query 'Acount' and 'Bcount' all at once.

Comment: Your conditional aggregation doesn't work. Remove `else 0` to get the correct count. (count() counts all non-null values, i.e. both 1 and 0 are counted.)

Answer (score 0):

Starting with MongoDB 4.2 you can use [aggregation pipelines](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/) to achieve this. You can use [SUM](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) with expression. It will be something like this:

```
db.table1.aggregate(
[
  {
    $group: 
    {
      _id: null,
      Acount: {$sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$isA", 1] }, 1, 0]}},
      Bcount: {$sum: {$cond: [{ $eq: ["$isB", 1] }, 1, 0]}}
    }
  }
]);
```

You can add [project](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to remove the `_id` from the result adding this:

```
  {
    $project: 
    {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
```

as element of the array past to the aggregation pipeline.